# Tuple Choices Django

Tags: django

If I have a GENDER_CHOICE Tuple in a model like so:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
```

Could I use Integers a swell:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'Male'),
    ('2', 'Female'),
)
```

And have a `IntegerField(max_length=1)` to write to ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, but `'1'` and `'2'` are not integers (although they might still work through some magic).

This would definitely work for an `IntegerField`:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Male'),
    (2, 'Female'),
)
```

I don't believe an `IntegerField` has a `max_length` attribute. A `PositiveSmallIntegerField` would be appropriate if you want a small number of choices.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [PositiveSmallIntegerField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) would be a better fit.